# What does this "AT" mean in nasm?

Tags: assembly, assemblies, nasm

Here is part of the code:

```
     pop ebp
     sub ebp,lime_reloc-@
     pop dword [ebp-@+para_ebp]
     mov [ebp-@+para_ebx],ebx
     mov [ebp-@+para_ecx],ecx
     mov [ebp-@+para_edx],edx
     mov [ebp-@+para_esp],esp
```

I am quite confused about the **@** , and I can not find it in the 
nasm [manual](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11/html/nasmdoc3.html)...

Could any one give me some help? Thank you!

Comment: Offset of current line?

Comment: Looking at the lime source, `@ equ $`, so Egor is correct. Apparently done just to obfuscate the source...